# How can I make concurrent calls in google-maps-services-python

Tags: python, google-maps, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I am trying to call the method `static_map` from `google-maps-services-python`.

I have a solution with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` but even passing a big `max_workers` I don't seem to exploit much parallelism. I get:

```
 WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Connection pool is full, discarding connection: maps.googleapis.com. Connection pool size: 10
```

Here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits it says I could get to 30,000 QPM (Queries Per Minute). So I should be able to make many API calls in parallel.

Can this be done or should I better call the URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?parameters myself without this library?

Here is my piece of code (I removed the initialization):

```py
import googlemaps
import concurrent.futures

client = googlemaps.Client(key='<MYKEY')

# addresses = [ list of addresses to search with Google Maps API ]
images_path = 'images/'

def download_google_maps(filename, address):
  filename = filename + '.png'
  f = open(filename, 'wb')
  for chunk in client.static_map(size=(600, 600),
                                center=address,
                                zoom=20,
                                format="png"):
      if chunk:
          f.write(chunk)
  f.close()
  message = 'Got Google Maps image in ' + filename
  print(message)
  return message

def download_images(index, address):
    filename = images_path + str(index)
    download_google_maps(filename, address)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    futures = []
    for i in range(len(addresses)):
        futures.append(executor.submit(download_images, i, addresses[i]))

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        try:
            result = future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception: {e}')
```

Comment: By any means, is your use case caching these static maps?

Comment: @Yrll hm. I was to download some images to do machine learning.

Comment: As I am no legal expert, please make sure that your use case is in compliance with their [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services.). 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services, specifically says there that it is not allowed to scrape nor cache Google Maps Content.

Comment: @Yrll thanks. Anyway I am just testing stuff now.